# Need Decimals in java calculator

Tags: java, math, calculator

I am making this calculator that works fine, but the user can't input decimal numbers. I don't know how to allow the user to do this. Please help!

```
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //ADD

            if (number1.getText().length() != 0)
                num1 = Float.parseFloat(number1.getText().toString());
            if (number2.getText().length() != 0)
                num2 = Float.parseFloat(number2.getText().toString());

            if (num1 == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter a 
number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (num2 == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please enter a 
number",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }


            resultnum = num1 + num2;
            result.setText(String.valueOf(resultnum));
        }
    });
```

The calculator works perfect and everything, it's just the decimals. I searched through the web, tried all websites, but I didn't find anything. Thanks!

Comment: That's a lot of code, can you please include only the relevant parts to the problem? would be easier for us to find a solution for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You have posted way to much code in your question, which makes it unclear to us (and to future readers) exactly where the problem is.  Please try to reduce your problem code to 10 lines or less.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score -1):

Seemingly you use Floats instead of double/BigDecimal (read about both and choose one which will be more useful for you)

Comment: Please improve this answer by explaining in greater depth the problems with the original poster's code and how your suggestions address these.

Comment: I used floats and doubles, but none gave me the result I wanted-to have decimals